# Visual Studio 2019 16.18.4 : .NET 5.0 installed yet not available for projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I have Visual Studio 2019 updated to the latest current version of 16.18.4 (see screenshot), the .NET 5.0 is installed (see screenshot made in visual studio installer) and yet when creating new projects or then changing
target framework, the .NET 5.0 framework is not available. In the about box Visual Studio displayed .NET 4.8, not .NET 5.0.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 4.8.04084 is the .NET Framework version. .NET 5 is *not* called .NET Framework 5 because it's *not* a .NET Framework version. You should learn the differences between .NET Framework (last version 4.8), .NET Core (last version 3.1) and .NET (only version at the moment is 5)

Comment: I know the difference but thank you Camilo for reminding me of how things stand. The problem is that things are probably not that clearly laid out in visual studio but even more things appear and disappear with updated (I remember some VS projects marked as .NET Core which have now disappeared and yet are still available but under a slightly different name).

Comment: Think of the .NET Framework shown at VS About dialog as debugging info for VS itself. I still got VS 2010 installed for old projects, and its About Box show .NET Framework version 4.8, even though we know VS 2010 only builds for .NET 4 at the latest.

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone else who might face a moment of confusion as I did, the following allows creating a .NET Framework Windows Forms project

[image]

while the following allows targeting either .NET Core 3.1 or the newer .NET 5.0

[image]

[image]

and, as said, you can't simply set from VS a .NET Framework project to target the new .NET 5.0.

Comment: Please do not use "pre-.NET 5.0" names or stuff like that, that only causes more confusion. The products are named .NET Framework (died in 4.8) and .NET (started in 5). Also, "fx" has nothing to do here. It is correct that you cannot magically upgrade .NET Framework to .NET targets though, as those are significantly different project types

Comment: Camilo don't feel so much the urge to edit other's posts. I will leave your edits in place but beware, I disagree with some of the edits you made.